# Azure resources not able to reach resources in same Virtual Network through App Gateway

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-web-app-service

I have an Azure container app environment with several Azure Container Apps within a private network accessible only through an APP Gateway. For the frontend, I have a static Web app within the same VNET and accessible only through the App Gateway.

**The problem:**

I noticed that the communication between container apps **is only working with the container apps private URLs**. And It doesn't work when it goes through the Gateway (as it's a request from the internet).
And the same is happening with the frontend. When a container app tries to reach the frontend (with puppeteer) the network is blocked because it's considered as an internal resource trying to reach another resource through the Gateway.

I've tried looking into outbound rules in the firewall and NSGs and I see that they are allowed, I can even reach any public url from my container apps (google.com ..Etc).

Does anyone know what could be happening?
Thanks !!

Comment: If NSG rules are allowed, verify that the Application Gateway is correctly configured to route traffic to both the Azure Container Apps and the static Web App. Check backend pools, routing rules, and DNS resolution to ensure proper configuration within the private network.

Comment: Are you trying to achieve the requirement using terraform @karimchaari?

Comment: @VinayB yes if possible!
Thanks !

Comment: please share the code your tried

Comment: and blocker info if any @KarimChaari

Answer (score 0):

> I tried Optimizing Internal Communications in Azure: Navigating Through NSG Configurations and Application Gateway.

Using an Application Gateway with Azure Container Apps and a frontend within a private network can bolster security, yet it may also complicate internal communications. Ineffectiveness in communication between container apps and the frontend through the Gateway often arises from misconfigured Network Security Groups (NSGs) or the suboptimal use of the Gateway for internal traffic.

To enhance internal service interactions, consider utilizing direct connections or Azure Private Link to bypass the Gateway. It's also essential to modify Network Security Group (NSG) rules to support these internal communications effectively.

I tried this terraform configuration below with the limited info I got from the query.

***My terraform query:***

```
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "testrg-vk"
  location = "East US"
}


resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "example" {
  name                = "vkVNet"
  address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "appgateway" {
  name                 = "vkGatewaySubnet"
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.example.name
  address_prefixes     = ["10.0.1.0/24"]
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "container_apps" {
  name                 = "vkcontainerAppsSubnet"
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.example.name
  address_prefixes     = ["10.0.2.0/24"]

}

resource "azurerm_log_analytics_workspace" "example" {
  name                = "vkWorkspace"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  sku                 = "PerGB2018"
  retention_in_days   = 30
}

resource "azurerm_container_app_environment" "example" {
  name                       = "vkEnvironment"
  resource_group_name        = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location                   = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  log_analytics_workspace_id = azurerm_log_analytics_workspace.example.id
}

resource "azurerm_network_security_group" "example" {
  name                = "vkNSG"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name

  security_rule {
    name                       = "allowHttpInbound"
    priority                   = 100
    direction                  = "Inbound"
    access                     = "Allow"
    protocol                   = "Tcp"
    source_port_range          = "*"
    destination_port_range     = "65200-65535"
    source_address_prefix      = "Internet"
    destination_address_prefix = "*"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_public_ip" "example" {
  name                = "vkPublicIP"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  allocation_method   = "Static"
  sku                 = "Standard"
}

resource "azurerm_application_gateway" "example" {
  name                = "vkAppGateway"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  sku {
    name     = "Standard_v2"
    tier     = "Standard_v2"
    capacity = 2
  }
  gateway_ip_configuration {
    name      = "vkGatewayConfig"
    subnet_id = azurerm_subnet.appgateway.id
  }
  frontend_port {
    name = "httpPort"
    port = 80
  }
  frontend_ip_configuration {
    name                 = "vkFrontendIPConfig"
    public_ip_address_id = azurerm_public_ip.example.id
  }
  backend_address_pool {
    name = "vkBackendPool"
  }
  backend_http_settings {
    name                  = "vkHttpSettings"
    cookie_based_affinity = "Disabled"
    port                  = 80
    protocol              = "Http"
    request_timeout       = 20
  }
  http_listener {
    name                           = "vkHttpListener"
    frontend_ip_configuration_name = "vkFrontendIPConfig"
    frontend_port_name             = "httpPort"
    protocol                       = "Http"
  }
  request_routing_rule {
    name                       = "vkRoutingRule"
    rule_type                  = "Basic"
    http_listener_name         = "vkHttpListener"
    backend_address_pool_name  = "vkBackendPool"
    backend_http_settings_name = "vkHttpSettings"
    priority                   = 100
  }
}

resource "azurerm_subnet_network_security_group_association" "container_apps_nsg_association" {
  subnet_id                 = azurerm_subnet.container_apps.id
  network_security_group_id = azurerm_network_security_group.example.id
}

resource "azurerm_subnet_network_security_group_association" "appgateway_nsg_association" {
  subnet_id                 = azurerm_subnet.appgateway.id
  network_security_group_id = azurerm_network_security_group.example.id
}
```

***`Deployment Succeeded:`***

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]